# Hibernate search on multiple class hierarchy

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

Let's provide class example:

abstract class SuperParent {
  superParentField1;
}

abstract class Parent extends SuperParent {
  parentField1;
}

class ImplementaingClass1 extends Parent {
  // I want to index parentField1 only
}

class ImplementingClass2 extends Parent {
  // I want to index superParentField1 only
}

And variations from these.

What's the best approach to handle this in hibernate-search? So I can do a search on any field at any given class. Do I need to override the field on the implementing class and add annotation there? Is there no other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the getter and add the `@Field` annotation on the overridden getter:

```
abstract class SuperParent { superParentField1; }

abstract class Parent extends SuperParent { parentField1; }

@Indexed
class ImplementingClass1 extends Parent {
  @Override
  @Field(... stuff ...)
  SomeType getParentField1() {
    return super.getParentField1();
  }
}

@Indexed
class ImplementingClass2 extends Parent {
  @Override
  @Field(... stuff ...)
  SomeType getSuperParentField1() {
    return super.getSuperParentField1();
  }
}
```

Or, use [programmatic mapping](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi). This would be especially relevant if you have more than a few fields with that kind of constraint.

Comment: I see thanks. That's what I was trying to avoid. Do you know what will happen if I have an id field in the SuperParent entity annotated with @DocumentId when I extend it and the extending class is not annotated with @Indexed? I just want to make sure that it will not cause any problem. Thanks.

Comment: @czetsuya If your really want to avoid this, you can use programmatic mapping as mentioned at the end of my answer. It's a bit more complex, but much more flexible. Regarding your question, only `@Indexed` types will be indexed, so you can add a `@DocumentId` in a supertype, it shouldn't affect non-`@Indexed` subtypes and should work with `@Indexed` subtypes.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can live with it :-).

Comment: @Yoaan, seems like this approach doesn't work for facet? It can't find the field with facet annotation. Note that id is also annotated with DocumentId.

Comment: @czetsuya I'm afraid I'll need more information, in particular the code and the stack trace. Maybe edit this question, or open another one?

Comment: Thanks Yoann. I was able to figure out the problem.